# Netbeans 8.0.2 installing native library error

Tags: java, netbeans, java-8

On my Windows 10 (x64) Laptop, I installed JDK8.151 (x64).

When I installed the Netbeans 8.2 (x64) (JavaSE) version from Netbeans website and ran it, an error appeared:

```
Cannot load native library from path:
native/jnilib/windows/windows-x64.dll
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

It appears you' ve not configured **JAVA_HOME**

can you show output of

```
echo %JAVA_HOME%
```

Comment: output : %JAVA_HOME%

Comment: How do I configure JAVA_HOME ?

Comment: I do all steps to set JAVA_HOME in Windows 10, however when i open command prompt and type in: echo %JAVA_HOME%  i get this output : %JAVA_HOME% and when i type in : javac -version i get this output : javac is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: NetBeans does not care about **JAVA_HOME**. It may be appropriate to set  **JAVA_HOME** correctly for other reasons, but its value is completely irrelevant to NetBeans, and its installer.

Comment: did you set %JAVA_HOME% for both user and system?